# how does the scheduler time quanta varies with number of threads?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

From what i understand, the default time before a scheduler performs preemption on a thread is around 100ms, how does this quanta varies with the number of busy threads(that need to be context switched)?

If there are 200 threads running and 100 of them were using ~100ms the other hundred would not be so happy.Is there some entity like a full thread circle time? on witch the quanta is based?

I have the Linux 3.2+ kernels in mind.

Comment: I believe the standard setting for HZ is 100 which would be 10ms.

Comment: Confirmed: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html

Answer (score 1):

The CFS approach is that each process would receive 1/n of the processor's time. 
It has a *targeted latency*. It is the time in which every process would receive a chance to execute some code.

To approach this, scheduler runs a process for a specified amount of time which called *timeslice*. Typically timeslice is targeted latency divided by number of running processes.

But when number of running processes aprroaches infinity, timeslice approaches zero. As this will eventually result in unacceptable switching costs, CFS imposes a floor on the timeslice assigned to each process.This floor is called the *minimum granularity*. By default it is 1 millisecond. Thus, even as the number of runnable processes approaches infinity, each will run for at least 1 millisecond, to ensure there is a ceiling on the incurred switching costs.